# Как запретить изменение пользователем размеров столбцов в JTable

Tags: java, swing

Как запретить изменение пользователем размеров столбцов в JTable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам нашел)

```
    int columnNumber=table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount();
    for (int i=0;i<columnNumber;i++){
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setResizable(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fixedTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

Comment: видимо, вы меня не правильно поняли. я хочу сделать так, что бы пользователь не мог изменять размер столбцов. ваше же решение просто задает поведение таблицы, при которым измненяет размер только столбец, который изменяется пользователем